# GeoLocation for all Mobile/Desktop Devices

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, mobile, geolocation, mobile-devices

I'm using [gears.js](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/gears_init.js) and [geo.js](http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript) in an attempt to cover all grounds, in terms of finding the user's geolocation. So if the user is using something less than IE9, I would possibly prompt install for Google Gears, so I know for desktop, IE7 + is covered.

For the mobile devices I'm looking at [geo](http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript)
which covers quite a few mobile devices.

I'm wondering if there is anything which accounts for WP7 geolocation as well using JavaScript, and if there is better ways of handling GeoLocation for all devices.

Not entirely sure how Google Gears work for IE7/8 also, so any elaboration on that would be great. (I'm not assuming Gears is the only/best way forward though for non geolocation supported browsers, so any correction on that is fine!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to the WP7 part of your question.
There is CURRENTLY no way to get geolocation from in the browser in IE on Windows Phone 7. This should change when the next version of the browser is released.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this today: http://geosenseforwindows.com/ it basically gives Wifi based geolocation to the Windows 7 Sensor API:

> Geosense is a Windows Sensor that
>   provides the Location and Sensors
>   platform in Windows 7 with accurate
>   and reasonably ubiquitous positioning
>   information without requiring or the
>   assistance of GPS hardware, enabling
>   more practical location-based
>   applications and scenarios on Windows
>   7.

Unfortunately I don't think IE can access that Sensor API without resorting to COM calls in your javascript.

We also use the free/commercial [GpsGate](http://gpsgate.com/products/gpsgate_client), which lets any browser on a Windows machine directly access a real hardware GPS device on the computer.